# Spark Cant able to find external jar

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark

I am using cassandra in Spark but getting following error.I tried add jar using --jar and --driver-class-path but it seems that spark is not adding jar in classpath.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/hadoop/ConfigHelper
```

Comment: could you post the full command line you're using?